# How install driver in linux

Tags: linux

HAi LInux

I bought acer P235H LCD monitor. I have installed centos5.4 . When i scroll down the window it shows frame by frame slowly. In linux the display property does not show the resolution of 1920 X 1080. Do any know the solution for this and is there any steps for installing driver in linux. Is the driver is seperate for linux and windows?.

Thank you

Comment: I've voted to close the other one. What graphics card do you have? That's more important than the monitor...

Comment: Yes more info is needed, what graphics card do you have? have you updated the drivers?

Comment: I have Nividea graphics card. How to install/update drive

Answer (score 3):

Here is the installation procedure for your driver: [Cent OS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/HardwareList/NvidiaDriver?action=show&redirect=HardwareList%2FNvidiaDriver)